# A Specific Image in Our README Does Not Appear in BitBucket Why?

Tags: html, bitbucket, readme

I have an Image hosted in our BitBucket repository and when I got to BitBucket to look at the code it does not render, though other images do. The `README` codeline that has the image is this:

```
<img align="right" width="60" height="60" src="images/terraform.png">

# tf-snowflake
```

Obviously, I have an image hosted in the repository that hosts the `README.md` and the image is a picture of the terraform logo. But essentially, that is the top 3 lines in the `README.md`, when I do this on `GitHub` it works, but it doesn't seem to work for BitBucket and it renders like this:

[image]

Why would it render like this, but on GitHub it would actually show the Image that is supposed to be aligned to the right-side of the `README` file?

Comment: Change the `src=""` to be an **absolute** URI, not a page-relative URI.

Comment: `<img align="right"` <-- It isn't 1995 anymore, don't use the obsolete `align=""` attribute. You probably want to use `<img style="float: right;"` instead.

Comment: They don't support HTML tags in read me, see https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/markdowndemo/src/master/ on how to have an image

Comment: That's sad, now I see why GitHub/GitLab made migration scripts to just move away from BitBucket. But thanks for the Information @Randommm, make an answer response so I can mark it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket's README standards don't support HTML tags. To read more about the allowed formatting, you can use their own example page https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/markdowndemo/src/master/

For images it would be

```
![Alt text](http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png)

![Alt text](http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png "Optional title")
```